# Animal motif for an organized horde of bandits?

Tags: society, names, organizations

There is supposed to be a bandit horde that is very well organized and terrorizes large parts of a province. It was thought that it had an animal motif, which is also its heraldic arms. Now that I'm at the sign, I can't think of anything that would fit bloodthirsty bandits. Hawk was originally meant to be, but that seems too ... noble to me.

Comment: A [wolf salient](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Complete_Guide_to_Heraldry/Chapter_12), a wolf rampant, a [boar's head erased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasure_(heraldry)), a cat-a-mountain sejant guardant erect, a [gryphon segreant](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Complete_Guide_to_Heraldry/Chapter_13), a [heraldic salamander](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Salamanders_in_heraldry), ...

Comment: Hi, Broken Ship, welcome to Worldbuilding! Your question is difficult to clearly answer, because there is no clear criteria which answer would be better.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to World building. Why is it that a Hawk Appears noble to you? Do the bandits think what they are doing is noble? Why are they even bandits in the first place? If its a Heraldic Arms, then why shouldn't it be noble in the first place? A noble who fell on hard times and resorts to banditry is hardly going to use a bad or evil animal to represent themselves. I hope these questions help you make a decision. Your question as it is, is too opinion based for there to be a correct answer.

Comment: Regrettably, [What is the best name for X](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6259#6259) questions are off-topic.  Such questions are rarely objective.  For more info please take our [tour] and visit our [help].

Comment: My first thought was the Spiders from Hunter x Hunter

Comment: Firstly it would help to know what creatures could exist in your setting, is it a province in Medieval Europe for example? Then any creature such as racoons or Komodo Dragons would not be appropriate as people in such a setting are unaware of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a spirit animal to represent your bandits, may I humbly suggest the Raccoon!

[image]

[image]

Looking at [this](https://dreamingandsleeping.com/raccoon-spirit-animal-symbolism-and-meaning/) site or [this](http://www.spiritanimal.info/raccoon-spirit-animal/) one provides some information about how the bandits could best be symbolized by this devious thief of an animal.

[image]

> **The Raccoon’s Mask** The most recognizable, physical trait of the raccoon is its mask. The spirit animal’s classification as a shape
>   shifter originates with this symbol of transformation.
>
> It is important to remember no one is exactly as he or she seems. *(Like how your bandits hide their true identities from non bandits)* This power animal’s mask is symbolic of humans’ ability to adapt or
>   shape shift in different situations. Masks have been used for
>   centuries by every society to achieve altered states. The art of mask
>   making has been has existed the world around and has been used for
>   celebration, ceremonies and magic rituals. Once behind a mask, a
>   person can become someone or something else. The mask helps us change
>   who and what we are to who and what we want to be.
>
> Having the raccoon as your totem is a helpful in revealing all the
>   facades of your personality. The raccoon spirit animal’s presence in
>   your life may be helping you to transform into something or someone
>   new.
>
> **The Adventurous Raccoon** Raccoons love to explore. By nature they are extremely curious. This often leads them to get into things they
>   shouldn’t *(Like how your bandits get into trouble with the law)*.
>   Their nighttime excursions are mini adventures and raccoons can cover
>   a lot of distance in an evening *(like your bandits)*. They are keen
>   to constantly explore new realms. The raccoon spirit animal may be a
>   sign that it’s time to get curious and start exploring!
>
> **The Courageous Raccoon** Raccoons are extremely courageous and can even be quite ferocious for small animals. Despite the raccoon’s
>   cleverness and emphatic nature, it will fight when it feels threatened
>   (Like a bandit would, fighting only when stealing easily cannot be
>   accomplished). Likewise, it teaches you to be aware of when to let
>   things slide and when you should stand up for yourself.
>
> **The Raccoon In Traditional Folklore** Many North American Indian tribes have long-viewed the raccoon as a trickster. The mischievous
>   raccoon is most frequently portrayed light-heartedly as a leading
>   character in children’s tales. The spirit animal is also the
>   inspiration for many Native American dances and is recognized, in
>   part, in rituals and ceremonies.
>
> Known for its stealthy ability to scavenge, the raccoon has the
>   uncanny ability to acquire what it needs, namely food, and escape
>   dangerous situations *(sound like a set of requirements for a criminal
>   group?)*. Its dexterity, such as the ability to open doors, sets it
>   apart from other spirit animals.
>
> Historically, the raccoon has also been a clan symbol for many tribes,
>   including the Chickasaw and Shawnee of Oklahoma and the Chippewa in
>   Minnesota.

Answer (score 1):

Wolf pack - vicious, bloodthirsty and organised. Also easy to work in a heraldry in a number of different ways. Prior to the common adoption of guns, wolves could be a huge problem for medieval society, as they could easily take down isolated humans.

Depending on the climate the may have adopted other animals, such as the Hyena,

Also, the bandits may have adopted a "noble" animal as their symbol out of a sense of sarcasm or irony.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bird, I might suggest a raven/corvid.  Black is often associated with evil.  Ravens have been known to be rather clever pilferers, as well being ruthless.  There are anecdotes about crows driving animals into traffic so that the would be killed by cars.

Hyenas could be a good choice for a mammal.  They are infamous for driving predators off of their kills.  (Though more research shows it is lions who are more likely to chase off jackals)  This would be especially apt for a female led group of bandits as jackal females are bigger stronger etc. than the males and have been observed raping the males using their clitoris.

For reptiles, a Komodo Dragon might be a good choice.  It is a Strong, venomous apex predator.  Dual phalluses as well for an excessively macho/rapey band of thieves.